# Arc not being rendered on 2D context in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I'm trying to render a simple circle on a canvas, and it works perfectly on Chrome, but fails on Safari.

Strange thing is that when I try to get x position of circle I get expected number, so it obviously exists but just doesn't render properly.

```
canvas.context.beginPath();
canvas.context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 153, 0, 1)';
canvas.context.lineWidth = 10;
canvas.context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
canvas.context.stroke();
canvas.context.closePath();
```

`width`, `height`, and `radius` are custom variables that are calculated in runtime, and sample values are

```
x = 155;
y = 155; 
radius = 25.5;
```

But it's not fixed and can be any number from certain range.

And this renders orange circle in Chrome, but nothing in Safari so any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. An issue was that `radius` was calculated to float number, and for some reason Safari wouldn't render an arc with radius of 25.5, so i had to do

```
Math.floor(radius)
```

Which basically solved my problem. I stil don't know why this happened, but there is a solution in case someone else has the same issue